# Forming Mockito "grammars"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Mockito seems like a pretty sweet stubbing/mocking framework for Java. The only problem is I can't find any concrete documentation on the best ways of using their API. Common methods used in tests include:

```
doXXX(???) : Stubber
when(T) : OngoingStubbing
then(T) : OngoingStubbing
verify(???) : T
given(T) : BDDOngoingStubbing
willXXX(???) : BDDStubber
```

When you see examples of Mockito in practice, you see code like:

```
when(yourMethod()).thenReturn(5);
```

From all the docs I've read, I've identified several "patterns" of Mockito "grammars" obtained from daisy-chaining these method calls together like the example above. Some common patterns I've found are:

> **When/Then:** when(yourMethod()).thenReturn(5);
>
> **Given/Will:** given(yourMethod()).willThrow(OutOfMemoryException.class);
>
> **Do/When:** doReturn(7).when(yourMock.fizzBuzz());
>
> **Will/Given/Do:** willReturn(any()).given(yourMethod()).doNothing();
>
> **Verify/Do:** verify(yourMethod()).doThrow(SomeException.class);

What I'm choking on is how to select the right pattern/combination of method calls to model my test cases. It seems like you can daisy-chain these together in seemingly endless combos and I'm not sure what pattern is right for which problem.

Can some Mockito Guru help shed some light as to which patterns/combinations of Mockito methods are used for which types of test cases (and why)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mockito often have several ways of doing things.

I find myself using mostly:

```
// Setup expectations
when(object.method()).thenReturn(value);
when(object.method()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(object.voidMethod());


// verify things
verify(object, times(2)).method();
verify(object, times(1)).voidMethod();
```

I've found that i can do 95% of what i need to with these three kinds of calls.

Also, what version of Mockito are you using?  "given" and "will" constructs are not present in the latest version (1.9.0+)

However, there are cases where I want the return value or exception to respond to the input.  In this case, you can use the Answer interface to inspect the method arguments and return an appropriate value.

```
public class ReturnFirstArg<T> implements Answer<T> {
    public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return invocation.getArguments()[0];
    }
}

when(object.method(7)).thenAnswer(new ReturnFirstArg<Integer>());
```

Comment: +1 There is also the [BDD](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/BDDMockito.html) syntax.

Comment: @Garret Hall : thanks for the pointer.  I have never used this class, but i suspect it's because i've never had to :)

Comment: Are you sure that `given` and `will` are not in Mockito 1.9.0 and higher?  I believe they're in the `BDDMockito` class.

Comment: As @Garret Hall pointed out, there' in the BDD syntax, which I have never used, so I stand corrected.

Comment: In fact that's what I have pointed out in my answer for BDD support... :P

Comment: Shouldn't the third line be `.when(object).voidMethod()`?

Answer (score 42):

There are several disadvantages to the `when/thenReturn`, `when/thenThrow` and `when/then` syntaxes.  For example,

- In the case of `when/thenReturn`, if the return type is a generic with a 
  wildcard, and you wish to return a mock of the same type, you will be unable 
  to avoid a compile warning.
- You can't use `when/thenThrow` and `when/then` for a void method.
- You can't use these syntaxes on Mockito spies.
- You can only call `when` once for each combination of mock object,
  method and arguments, unless you call `reset` on the mock.
- Calling `when` multiple times for one combination of mock
  object and method, when you are using argument matchers, can lead to problems.

I find these cases difficult to remember.  So instead of trying to keep track of when the 
`when/thenReturn`, `when/thenThrow` and `when/then` syntaxes will and won't work, I prefer to avoid them completely, in favour of the `doReturn/when`, `doThrow/when` and `doAnswer/when` alternatives.  That is to say, since you'll occasionally need `doReturn/when`, `doThrow/when` and `doAnswer/when`, and you can ALWAYS use these methods, there is no point in learning how to use `when/thenReturn`, `when/thenThrow` and `when/then`.

Note that `doReturn`, `doThrow` and `doAnswer` can be chained together in the same way as `thenReturn`, `thenThrow` and `then`.  What they don't have is an option for returning several values (or throwing several exceptions, or running several answers) within a single call to `doReturn`, `doThrow` and `doAnswer`.  But I find that I need to do this so seldom, that it doesn't really matter.

There's one more disadvantage to `doReturn`, which I consider insignificant.  You don't get compile time checking of the type of its argument, like you do with `when/thenReturn`.  So if you get the argument type wrong, you won't find out until you run your test.  Frankly, I don't care.

In summary then, I have been using Mockito for more than two years, and I consider the consistent use of `doReturn`, `doThrow` and `doAnswer` to be a Mockito best practice.  Other Mockito users disagree.

Comment: probably just my personal opinion, the biggest advantage of `when/then` to me is its readability. It is so much more fluent to read compared to `doXxx/when`.

Comment: @AdrianShum I understand your point; truly I do.  But I find the two forms equally readable.  I believe it ultimately comes down to what you're used to.  For a Mockito beginner starting out, I have no hesitation recommending the do/when forms.

Comment: I agree with @david-wallace. Readability is very subjective; consistency is not. Compile-time type-safety is not important here since your test would find it later. The [Mockito docs](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn%28java.lang.Object%29) should be amended on this point.

Comment: I find the biggest thing that `do*/when` misses is my IDE letting me know for changes.  If I change a return type (`List` to `Set`, for example), all of the `when/then` get flagged and I know to go change them.  I don't know this until the tests fail with `do*/when`.  Obviously I _will_ be running the tests, I just find it's a less neat way to identify cases, and potentially requires me to run them multiple times.

Answer (score 10):

The things in fact looks much simpler than you thought

REF: http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.12/org/mockito/Mockito.html

**Verify**:

In order to use Mockito, you need to understand one basic philosophy of Mockito: Stubbing and Verification is separated.  Therefore, the "Verify/Do" you mentioned is in fact doing the "Verification" job, while the other 4 "grammars" is for stubbing.  Stubbing define how the mock object will react in different situation.  Verification is to make sure what the mocks is invoked as expected, in previous invocation to system under test (SUT).

**When/Then , Given/Will**:

Then it come to the "When" and "Given" families.  You can simply treat them as aliases of each other.  "Given" family is added in Mockito 1.8.x as to make it looks more aligned to BDD practices.

**DoXxx**:

In normal case we mostly use `when(xxx).then(...)` (and `given(...).will(...)` ) .  However there are some case that syntax is not working.  The most obvious case is when return type of the stubbed method is void.  In such case `when(mockObj.voidMethod()).thenThrow(anException)` is not going to compile.  As a workaround, an alternative syntax of Do/When is created, so you can write the previous line as `doThrow(anException).when(mockObj.voidMethod())`

Comment: Thanks @Adrian - your link is broken

Comment: Link fixed.  In fact it is just the "Documentation" link from mockito.org