# How to tell a Mockito Mock annotation to return a mock object which is not null?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to unit test a method, which has different branches depending upon the value of an object that is created inside it. The below code demonstrates it.

```
public class AClass {

public void method2() {
  //Some code goes here
}
public void method1(BClass bObject) {
    C_Class cObject = bObject.someMethodThatReturnsC();
    if(cObject != null) {
        method2();
        method2();
    }
}}
```

Below is the TestClass:

```
public class AClassTest {
@InjectMocks
AClass AClassSpy;

@Mock
BClass b_objectMock;

@Mock
C_Class c_objectMock;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
  AClassSpy = spy(new AClass());      
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

public void method1Test () {
    doReturn(c_objectMock).when(b_objectMock).someMethodThatReturnsC());
    AClassSpy.method1(b_objectMock);
    verify(AClassSpy, times(2).method2();
}
}
```

However, it always FAILS, since the c_objectMock is always null. What do I do to tell Mockito to not to return a null object?

Answer (score 2):

It works good, just use `@Before` annotation from junit, not `@BeforeMethod`, and mark your test method like `@Test` and remove second bracket from
`doReturn(c_objectMock).when(b_objectMock).someMethodThatReturnsC())<-this one;`
and add bracket at verify:
`verify(AClassSpy, times(2)<-here.method2();`
And just take care of your code!

This should work:

```
public class AClassTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private AClass AClassSpy;

  @Mock
  private BClass b_objectMock;

  @Mock
  private C_Class c_objectMock;

  @Before
  public void beforeMethod() {
      AClassSpy = spy(new AClass());
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void method1Test() {
      doReturn(c_objectMock).when(b_objectMock).someMethodThatReturnsC();
      AClassSpy.method1(b_objectMock);
      verify(AClassSpy, times(2)).method2();
  }

}
```

Instead of before method you can use annotation `@RunWith`. It looks clearly:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AClassTest {

  @Spy
  @InjectMocks
  private AClass AClassSpy;

  @Mock
  private BClass b_objectMock;

  @Mock
  private C_Class c_objectMock;

  @Test
  public void method1Test() {
      doReturn(c_objectMock).when(b_objectMock).someMethodThatReturnsC();
      AClassSpy.method1(b_objectMock);
      verify(AClassSpy, times(2)).method2();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having this behaviour because you are not mocking property the call to `someMethodThatReturnsC`.

[It should be](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12):

```
doReturn(c_objectMock).when(b_objectMock).someMethodThatReturnsC();
```

Comment: when(...) thenReturn(...) makes a real method call just before it is mocked. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when) , and I don't want to use it because it since someMethodThatReturnsC() can throw some Exception.

Comment: @Caesar I just tested and the test passes correctly with this modification.

Comment: @Tunaki it also passes without making modifications (except fixing parentheses)

Comment: @zubergu The OP has edited his post to fix his error with my answer.