# How to get an empty Stubber with Mockito for programatic stubbing

Tags: java, mockito

Normally with Mockito, if you're stubbing a method that gets called multiple times, you'd do

```
Mockito
    .doReturn(0)
    .doReturn(1)
    .doReturn(2)
    .when(mock).getValue();
```

I'd like to programaitcally stub a method that gets called multiple times, something like

```
Stubber stubber;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    stubber.doReturn(i);
}
stubber.when(mock).getValue();
```

My problem is there doesn't seem to be a *public* `Stubber` factory method. There's `org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.stubber()` and `new org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubberImpl()`, but both are internal, and using them feels wrong.

Is there a better pattern for programatically stubbing like this? Is there a better way to get an empty `Stubber`?

One solution would be `when().thenReturn()`, but I've been avoiding that since reading on [the difference between doReturn() and then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only official way to get a Stubber is to call `doReturn` or `doAnswer` (etc).

The better pattern for stubbing like that is to use [returnsElementsOf](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsElementsOf(java.util.Collection)):

```
List<Integer> returnValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    returnValues.add(i);
}
doAnswer(returnsElementsOf(returnValues)).when(mock).getValue();
```

You can also pass in an Array into `doReturn`, which already takes an array-compatible varargs, but only as its two-parameter overload:

```
int[] returnValues = new int[7];
for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i) {
    returnValues[i] = i;
}
doReturn(0, returnValues).when(mock).getValue();
```

Comment: I've tried this with a spy object and it only works for `doAnswer` on void methods but not for `doReturn` on non-void methods. Is it just me or can you confirm this?

Comment: @lazlev Well, I made a silly mistake and swapped `doReturn` and `doAnswer`, so let me fix that first. What behavior do you see in the errant `doReturn` case you mentioned?

Comment: I'm getting `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
            ReturnsElementsOf cannot be returned by methodName()`. I'm sending in a list of strings as the method I'm mocking is returning a string.

Comment: OK, swapping `doReturn` to `doAnswer` fixed the error I was mentioning. I also tried using `returnsElementsOf` with a list of `Answer<Void>` to dynamically mock the behavior of a void method. Unfortunately this is not working and fails silently...