# Mockito counting stubbing as invocation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

Trying to stub a class with 2 possible invocation/return paths using custom Matcher ... ran into an interest problem.

Here is a test I wrote to illustrate ...

This might be difficult to implement, but I would have expected the 1st `ArgumentMatcher` is not invoked when stubbing the second `when(...).thenReturn(...)`

But running the code below prints `foobar` on stdout. Is there anything we can do to prevent this behavior? Or am I using the wrong pattern by trying to stub a single mock with multiple custom `ArgumentMatcher`

FYI - `powermock` is on my classpath for other tests (not sure if that matters but I do see it in the stack trace)

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        File file = mock(File.class);
        when(file.list(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<FilenameFilter>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                System.out.println("foobar");
                return 1 + 1 >2;
            }
        }))).thenReturn(null);
        // at this point, mockito will attempt to run the previous matcher, treating this stub code as invocation ... and printing out 'foobar'
        when(file.list(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<FilenameFilter>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                System.out.println("barbar");
                return true;
            }
        }))).thenReturn(null);

    }
}
```

**EDIT** added comments to help illustrate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `doReturn()` syntax, then the method is not called.

```
doReturn(null).when(file).list(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<FilenameFilter>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        System.out.println("barbar");
        return true;
    }
}));
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29394497/862594) for more details. Also, [the docs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.27/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) explain this use-case (emphasis mine):

> You can use doReturn(), [...] in place of the corresponding call with when(), for any method. It is necessary when you:
>
> - stub void methods
> - stub methods on spy objects (see below)
> - **stub the same method more than once, to change the behaviour of a mock in the middle of a test.**