# why Mock object has doreturn and thenreturn for mock?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Note: I understand that in spy we can differenciate among these two.
I went all over internet but I still some doubts on doreturn/when and when/thenreturn in Mockito .Below is my doubt,

1)Are doreturn/when and when/thenreturn acts same for mock object ?
i.e: its does not matter whether you call doreturn/when or when/thenreturn for a mock object it will not call real method , but a stubbed call.
is my understanding is correct on this ?

2)doreturn/when and when/thenreturn makes a difference only for spy objects in Mockito.
i.e doreturn/when - will not call real methos and when/thenreturn will call real method.Is my understanding correct on this ?

If my understanding on above 2 points are correct then we should always use doreturn/when so that we dont need to learn 2 syntax ,Right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when)

Comment: its not duplicate, i want to know why doReturn and when are present in mock ? are those same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing by my own I came to know that:

1. doreturn/when and when/thenreturn are same for mocked object. None of them call the actual method
2. doreturn/when and when/thenreturn have different behaviour for spied object.
   doreturn/when - it will not call real method on spied object
   when/thenreturn - it will call real method on spied object

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

The [Mockito documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html) for `doReturn()` states:

> You can use doThrow(), doAnswer(), doNothing(), doReturn() and doCallRealMethod() in place of the corresponding call with when(), for any method. It is necessary when you
>
> - stub void methods
> - stub methods on spy objects (see below)
> - stub the same method more than once, to change the behaviour of a mock in the middle of a test.

and also...

> Use doReturn() in those rare occasions when you cannot use when(Object).

With an example given of...

> when(mock.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
>
> //Impossible: the exception-stubbed foo() method is called so RuntimeException is thrown.
>       when(mock.foo()).thenReturn("bar");
>
> //You have to use doReturn() for stubbing:
>      doReturn("bar").when(mock).foo();

In general, you should use the `when(...).thenReturn(...)` syntax and the occasions when the `doReturn(...).when(...)` syntax is useful are rare. However, it's important to note that the `when(...)` pattern is required for mocking void methods, which are not rare. It's just the `doReturn(...)` syntax which is less commonly used.

To specifically answer your questions:

1. No, the two syntaxes work slightly differently - the 'doReturn(...)' is able to set up the mock object to record a behaviour *before* the mocked method is called, whereas the 'when(...)' syntax works by doing some behind-the-scenes jiggery-pokery to set up a stub handler which the 'thenReturn(...)' method can work on. They'll *usually* have the same effect but the implementation differences become apparent in the corner case above.
2. For a mock, `when(...)` calls the stubbed method on the mock object. That's why the corner case above around re-defining the stubs behaviour is important.