# Why I get NullPointerException while mocking?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, spy

Why do I get NullPointerException?

Here is my code:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
class SomeDao {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "some-value")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return this.entityManager;
}

public long getNextId() {
    long someLongValue = getEntityManager().someMethod();
    //some code
    return someLongValue;
}
}

class SomeTest() {
@Spy
private SomeDao dao = new SomeDao();

@Test
public void someTestMethod() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(dao.getNextId()).thenReturn(10L);
}
}
```

When I run the test I get the following exception:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.some.api.some.package.dao.SomeDao.getNextId(SomeDao.java:13)
    ...

Later I want to add new classes to mock, and the getNextId method will be called inside one of them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use @Spy, you cannot use when/thenReturn syntax.

You must use doReturn/when syntax.

See also this post: [Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when)

So either changing your @Spy to @Mock or changing your stubbing, will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the annotation to Mock and it solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 3):

[MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) should be executed before test method, in JUnit

> ```
>   @Before public void initMocks() {
>        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
>    }
> ```

Or in TestNG use `@BeforeMethod`

> `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` method has to called to initialize annotated fields.
>
> In above example, initMocks() is called in @Before (JUnit4) method of test's base class.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't solve it :( I changed the Spy annotation to Mock then it succeeded.