# How to call real method on condition of spied object in Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spy

I need to be able to call a real method of spy object based on some condition. I.e. if condition is true then call real method otherwise do something else.

To be clear, I need to throw an exception on first call and call real method on a second call. Is it possible to achieve by using Mockito?

```
Object object = Mockito.spy(new Object());

// On the first call I need to throw an exception like this
Mockito.doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(object).toString();

// On the second call I need to call a real method
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(object).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for very helpful answer! Love cats <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, use `when(...).then(...)`, as that allows for "fluent chaining" of mock specifications:

```
Object object = Mockito.spy(new Object());
Mockito.when(object.toString()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException()).thenReturn("yeha");

try {
  System.out.println(object.toString());
  fail();
} catch(RuntimeException r) {
  System.out.println(object.toString());
}
```

Prints:

> yeha

Yeha!

Seriously: you should prefer `when(mock.foo()).then...` anyway (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when) for a list of reasons why that is). There are a few situations where `doReturn().when()` needs to be used, but as said: it is your last resort, not your first choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It is what I need!

Comment: This is not the answer unfortunately - using this methodology the Spied class will call the real method whilst setting up the mock. This may not be appropriate.