# Implement JUnit test for Spring Service

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I want to implement JUUNit test for this Spring Service:

```
        @Service
        public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
            private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("binlistsService")
            private BinlistsService binlistsService;

            public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {        
            }

            public PaymentResponse validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Merchants merchant, Contracts contract, Terminals terminal,
                      PaymentTransaction message, HttpServletRequest request) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

                     List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");

                     Optional<BinLists> db_bin_list = binlistsService.findByName(billing_address_country);
             }
       }
```

I tried this JUnit test:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BinCountryCheckFilter binCountryCheckFilter;

    private BinlistsService binlistsService = Mockito.mock(BinlistsService.class);  
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);

    @Mock
    List<RiskFilters> riskFiltersList = null;

    Optional<BinLists> binList = null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);             
        riskFiltersList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>(); 

        RiskFilters filter = new RiskFilters();
        riskFiltersList.add(filter);    

        BinLists binLists = new BinLists();
        binList = Optional.of(binLists);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {

        when(riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString())).thenReturn(riskFiltersList);
        when(binlistsService.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(binList);

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");

        Optional<BinLists> bin = binlistsService.findByName("US");

        BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl();

        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter(merchant, contract, terminal, authorizeTransactiontMockup(), request);
    }
```

The code is working fine when I try to mock the requests with `when`..... but it fails when I call the actual Spring Service in order to test it with NPE at this line at the Service Java Class `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl`:

`List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");`

How I can mock this SQL query?

Comment: is this an interface? `riskFilterService` and/or this is spring data repository?

Comment: I'm not sure about autowiring fields like this, if you make them constructor parameters you have more control over them. Is that part of your problem maybe, that the fields you autowire are null?

Comment: your question is unclear. Please put the NPE stacktrace that you are getting.

Comment: Yes, it's a Java Interface

Comment: @Randycan you elaborate a little bit what will be the advantage of using params with constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `riskFilterService` is an interface and/or spring repository.

Can you try mock like:

```
doReturn(riskFiltersList).when(riskFilterService).findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(any(), any()));
```

This (doReturn/when) pretty much avoids calling the method than compared to when/return

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29394497/2931410