# How to automatically replace Mockito thenReturn with Mockito doReturn

Tags: java, mockito

Mockito offers two ways to return certain values: the `thenReturn` and the `doReturn` syntax. The differences between the two are already documented [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when). I'm currently working on a Java class where the two syntaxes are mixed. I'm looking for an automated way to transform `thenReturn` to `doReturn`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in IntelliJ via the [custom structural search inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html):

```html
<replaceConfiguration name="when" text="when($mock$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)).thenReturn($result$)" recursive="false" caseInsensitive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" reformatAccordingToStyle="false" shortenFQN="false" replacement="doReturn($result$).when($mock$).$MethodCall$($Parameter$)">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="mock" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="result" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="MethodCall" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Parameter" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

You can just import this template from clipboard and save the custom inspection. Then you can run it via "Run inspection by name => structural search".