# NPE in Mockito argument matcher with doReturn causing all other tests to fail

Tags: java, mockito, testng, stub, argument-matcher

I am using `TestNG` along with `Mockito` for my test classes. I tried to create a `spy` object and used `ArgumentMatchers` to stub a method call. While using argument matchers, Mockito states that to match a primitive type we need to use `anyLong()`,`anyInt()`,`anyChar()` or something similar depending on the required argument type. So in this case if we use `any()` then it would cause a `NullPointerException`.

I tried three methods:

1. `NPE` would be thrown because I used `any()` to match a primitive argument
2. `NPE` would be thrown because I used `throw new NullPointerException()`
3. No exceptions thrown.

The below is the code I have used. (I have used `static imports` for `Mockito` methods)

```java
@Test
public class MyTest {
    class Something {
        public int someMethod(long someLong, int someInt, Set<Long> someSet) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        Something s = spy(new Something());
        doReturn(5).when(s).someMethod(any(), any(), any()); // NPE
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo(){
        Something s = spy(new Something());
        if(0==0) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        doReturn(5).when(s).someMethod(anyLong(), any(Integer.class), any());
    }

    @Test
    public void testThree() {
        Something s = spy(new Something());
        doReturn(5).when(s).someMethod(anyLong(), any(Integer.class), any()); // no issues
    }
}
```

Observations :

1. If I run the whole class, then all methods would FAIL. `testThree` throws `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`
2. If I run the third method alone, then it would PASS.
3. If i comment `testOne` and then run the whole run class, then `testTwo` would FAIL and `testThree` would PASS.

In my observation above, 2 and 3 are as expected. But I don't understand why `testThree` is also failing in observation 1. When I check the console, it shows that

> This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher us returning an object like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument.

So my question is **Why should a test method fail due to an issue with a previous test method?**

(Also, if I rename `testOne` to `testZZ` so that it executes last according to alphabetical order then `testThree` would PASS when test run at the class level.)

Comment: The last test fails when the whole test class is run because Mockito is keeping track of the already created mocks in the background. In case of a serious error which in this case is `UnfinishedStubbingException` in the first test, Mockitos' internal state is invalid.

Comment: @SzaPe any specific reason why it could have been implmented like that?

Comment: I can only guess. 
When using `when(s.someMethod(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(5);` instead of `doReturn(5).when(s).someMethod(any(), any(), any());` it only results in testOne failing.
I assume it has to do something with you first specifying the return value then only later adding what method call needs that return value. The `doReturn` sets an intermediate state, but the `when` part never completes at runtime due to the NPE.

Both is acutally valid format and this far I thought it's just a matter of preference which one to use, but it seems there is more difference in the background.

Comment: Also you should read the javadoc on the `doReturn` method. It starts as:

> `Use doReturn() in those rare occasions when you cannot use when(Object).`

So the doc might shed some light on the why.

Comment: @SzaPe I think `doReturn` is recommended with spy objects. Check this answer including the comments : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360269