# mockito, when setup mock stub using when/thenReturn it got exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

having a class and would like to mock/stub one method

```
public class ToBeMocked {
    public List<HttpCookie> mergeList(@NonNull List<HttpCookie> cookies, HttpCookie oneCookie) {
        
        System.out.println("+++ mergeList(), cookies:"+cookies+", oneCookie:"+oneCookie);

        HashMap<String, HttpCookie> map = new HashMap();
        if (oneCookie != null) {
            map.put("A", oneCookie);
        }
        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {  //<=== it crashed at this line
            map.put(cookie.getName(), cookie);
        }

        List<HttpCookie> list = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, HttpCookie> entry : map.entrySet()) {
           list.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

the test;

```
@Test
public void test() {

        List<HttpCookie> aCookieList = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpCookie a1Cookie = new HttpCookie("A1", "a1");
        HttpCookie a2Cookie = new HttpCookie("A2", "a2");
        aCookieList.add(a1Cookie);
        aCookieList.add(a2Cookie); 
        
        HttpCookie bCookie = new HttpCookie("B", "b1");

        List<HttpCookie> fakeCookieList = new ArrayList<>();
        fakeCookieList.add(bCookie);
        fakeCookieList.addAll(aCookieList);

    ToBeMocked theSpy = spy(new ToBeMocked());

    System.out.println("+++ 111 test(), aCookieList:"+aCookieList+", bCookie:"+bCookie);
        
    //when(theSpy.mergeList(any(List.class), any(HttpCookie.class)))
    when(theSpy.mergeList(eq(aCookieList), any(HttpCookie.class))). //<== exception on this
           .thenReturn(fakeCookieList);

    System.out.println("+++ 222 test()");
    // test
    // it would call some other function which internally call the mergeList(aCookieList, bCookie), and expect to generate a list from the stubbed result to use, here just make it simple to be run able to show the problem
    List<HttpCookie> list = theSpy.mergeList(aCookieList, bCookie);
        
    // verify
    assertEquals(list.contains(bCookie), true);        
}
```

got exception `NullPointerException` on the `when(theSpy.mergeList(any(List.class), any(HttpCookie.class))).thenReturn(fakeCookieList);`.

the log shows two lines:

```
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28
+++ 111 test(), aCookieList:[A1="a1", A2="a2"], bCookie:B="b1"
+++ mergeList(), cookies:null, oneCookie:null

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Apparently mergeList() got executed with null params, and crashed at
`for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies)`

Question:

thought the when().thenReturn() is just for setting up the stub, which was saying when the mock's mergeList() is called with any params (or with specific params), it should return the list provided.

is the when().thenReturn() not with proper params?
why it seems to execute the mergeList() in the when().thenReturn()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mockito [doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy):

> Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use when(Object) for
> stubbing spies. Therefore when using spies please consider
> doReturn|Answer|Throw() family of methods for stubbing.

So try it so:

```
  doReturn(fakeCookieList).when(theSpy)
            .mergeList(eq(aCookieList), any(HttpCookie.class));
```

But in general it is not quite clear what you are testing with such a test. The method under test is `mergeList`, at the same time you specify its behavior(return value) by calling `doReturn` and only returned value is checked in the end. (Of course, if the real code is fully represented)

Comment: Lvoov, thx for sharing! Tried doReturn() as well, same problem. The function here is much simplified just to show what problem is. In general it is to stub a function and stub causes it gets executed with null param, hence crashed.

Comment: Hm, it's really weird. For me and for this snippet of code, if I use `thenReturn` it throws `NullPointerException` (method `mergeList` is invoked with nulls, so just like yours) and  with `doReturn` it works.

Comment: I tried again and it work as you said, +1. But not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

@George Lvov's solution works.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when#:%7E:text=Stubbing%20void%20methods%20is%20one,re%20returning%2C%20at%20compile%20time.) explains the difference between doReturn(...) and theReturn(...), especially in spy the `doReturn(...)` will not make the real method call.
But have not find where it is documented the behavior difference.

*Both approaches behave differently if you use a spied object (annotated with @Spy) instead of a mock (annotated with @Mock):
when(...) thenReturn(...) makes a real method call just before the specified value will be returned. So if the called method throws an Exception you have to deal with it / mock it etc. Of course you still get your result (what you define in thenReturn(...))
doReturn(...) when(...) does not call the method at all.*