# Overriding @TestConfiguration mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, javabeans

There is a mock for a service below:

```
@TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public UserService userServiceBean() {
            UserService mock = mock(UserService.class);
            doReturn(12l).when(mock).getCompanyId();
            return mock;
        }
    }
```

This affects other UT where I want to return some other companyId such as:

```
when(userService.getCompanyId()).thenReturn(155l); <-- this mock is not working
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where you can't use `when/thenReturn`. Stubbing void methods is one such. Others include use with Mockito spies, and stubbing the same method more than once.

Reference: [Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20353846/6784846)