# Is it possible to invoke mocked object's method in constructor?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

I have, for example, these classes with Spring Boot. I try to do a REST API without a database and wieh files as data. The data files are like this:

> {
> "persons": [
> { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6512", "email":"jaboyd@email.com" },
> { "firstName":"Jacob", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6513", "email":"drk@email.com" }
> ] }

```java
@Repository
public class PersonRepository {

    private List<Person> persons;
    private DataLoaderService loaderService;
  
    @Autowired
    public PersonRepository(DataLoaderService loaderService){
        persons = loaderService.convertJsonToPojo("Persons",Person.class);
    }
    
    public List<Person> getAll(){
        return persons;
    }

}

@Service
public class DataLoaderService {

    private JsonFileService jsonFileService;
    private ObjectMapper mapper

    @Autowired
    public DataLoaderService(JsonFileService jsonFileService,ObjectMapper mapper){
        this.jsonFileService = jsonFileService;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public <T> List<T> convertJsonToPojo(String nodeName, Class <T> classOfT){
         
    }

}
```

So, I have a file. How can I read to transform to a list of Pojo?

When I want to mock the test method `getAll()`, my list size is 0. The mock doesn't give me values because I think the problem is **that I initialized the value in the constructor.** Here is my test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PersonRepositoryTest {
    
    PersonRepository repository;
    
    @Mock
    private DataLoaderService loaderService;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        repository = new PersonRepository(loaderService);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllPersonnesInConstructor() {
        List<Person> mockedList = Arrays.asList(                
                new Person("Paul","Moes","1", "7777", "adresse tour", "Chicago", "pauln@gmail.com"),
                new Person("Eleson","Moc","2", "77777", "ddkdkd", "New York", "eleson@gmail.com")
                );
        doReturn(mockedList).when(loaderService).convertJsonToPojo("persons",Person.class);
        
        List<Person> persons = repository.getAll();

        assertEquals(2,persons.size(),"Expected list size is 2");
        assertEquals(persons,mockedList);
    }

}
```

If i use `@Spy`, I have an error.

When I use method `getAll()` without initializing the variable persons in the constructor but in the method `getAll`, it is OK, like this:

```java
public List<Person> getAll() {
        this.persons = this.dataLoaderService.convertJsonToPojo("persons", Person.class);
        log.debug("persons getALL repository" + persons);
        return this.persons;
}
```

What can I do to test it?

Test a method which initializes a value in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your test:

1. You mock `convertJsonToPojo("persons", Person.class)`, whereas `PersonRepository` does `convertJsonToPojo("Persons", Person.class)`. Note "**p**ersons" vs. "**P**ersons".
2. When `PersonRepository` invokes the `convertJsonToPojo` method on your mock, you didn't stub (`doReturn` etc.) anything so far. This is why you get the default answer, i.e., a list of size 0.

To make it work, modify your test as follows:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PersonRepositoryTest {

    PersonRepository classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    DataLoaderService dataLoaderServiceMock;

    @Test
    void getAllPersonnesInConstructor() {
        List<Person> pojos = List.of(
                new Person("Paul", "Moes", "1", "7777", "adresse tour", "Chicago", "pauln@gmail.com"),
                new Person("Eleson", "Moc", "2", "77777", "ddkdkd", "New York", "eleson@gmail.com")
        );
        when(dataLoaderServiceMock.convertJsonToPojo("Persons", Person.class)).thenReturn(pojos);
        classUnderTest = new PersonRepository(dataLoaderServiceMock);

        List<Person> persons = classUnderTest.getAll();

        assertEquals(persons, persons);
    }

}
```

Now stubbing happens *before* the actual invocation of `convertJsonToPojo`.

Side notes:

- There is no need for `doReturn`, you can use `when`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360269/3429133
- There is also no need for two `assertEquals`. Checking for equality of the list includes the list's size.