# Stubbing a @SpyBean in Spring Boot test is failing with IllegalArgumentException: Aggregate instance must not be null

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, spy, spring-data-jdbc

I am having an ordinary spring boot integration test, which works fine with `@Autowired` and `@MockBean`, having all real, just the rest templates to the outside world are mocked

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@ExtendWith(ConsoleReporterExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@SpringJUnitConfig(Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {TestcontainersInitializer.class}) // for some docker DB
...
@Autowired
private SomeRepository someRepository;
```

then I needed to simulate an issue during persistence and decided to spy on the bean:

```
//@Autowired
@SpyBean
private SomeRepository someRepository;
```

Rest of the tests are still working fine, so the spied bean is properly propagated inside the app and because it is not stubbed it just behaves same like as it was auto-wired.
But when I stub it to throw an one-time exception during `save`

```
when(someRepository.save(any()))
            .thenThrow(new OptimisticLockingFailureException("some concurrency issue"))
            .thenCallRealMethod();
```

it fails on that stubbing, as if someone is passing `null` to the save method, but it is not the case, especially that we are not there yet, rather it happens during the stubbing definition. What am I missing? (spring boot v2.7.10)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Aggregate instance must not be null!

at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:153)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy223.save(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.ReflectionMemberAccessor.invoke(ReflectionMemberAccessor.java:48)
at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ForwardsInvocations.answer(ForwardsInvocations.java:49)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:110)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:34)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:82)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptAbstract(MockMethodInterceptor.java:161)
at SomeRepository$MockitoMock$cs2Dymza.save(Unknown Source)
at SomeRepository$MockitoMock$cs2Dymza$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b0e4e380.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at SomeRepository$MockitoMock$cs2Dymza$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6546aaba.save(<generated>)
```

Btw the repo is just a Crud one (even tried a hack to explicitly override the save method, but this obviously did not change anything)

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {

//<S extends SomeEntity> S save(S entity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it fails on that stubbing, as if someone is passing `null` to the save method, but it is not the case, especially that we are not there yet, rather it happens during the stubbing definition.

In fact, it is the case. You are invoking the method and passing `null` right here in this line:

```
when(someRepository.save(any()))
```

For reference, here's the implementation of [`ArgumentMatchers#any`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/fd628849447118a7da076a7005ad09e0681b731d/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.java#L140):

```
public static <T> T any() {
    reportMatcher(Any.ANY);
    return null; // <- returns null
}
```

Java is eagerly evaluated and always invokes methods before passing their return value to another method. `when(obj.method())` *must* invoke `method()` before `when` can be called. Mockito cannot change this fact.

If you want to avoid calling the method, use the [`doThrow`/`doCallRealMethod`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) forms:

```
doThrow(new OptimisticLockingFailureException("some concurrency issue"))
  .doCallRealMethod()
  .when(someRepository)
  .save(any());
```

More info:

- [Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I obviously overlooked the obvious ;)
Now I am further, but due to the fact that the repos are interfaces, mockito complains about
`Cannot call abstract real method on java object!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.`

I will look into this, how to solve, unless u know it ad-hoc

Comment: @radio do you have a real method or not? The error message would suggest the latter

Comment: well this is the ordinary way of defining a repository as an interface extending a spring data repository interface, so from mockito's perspective it is an abstract thing, but spring is instantiating it properly in runtime

Comment: Interesting enough, it seems like a missing feature to provide an easy way to express a one-time failure in spring data repositories, followed by a call to the real method. To solve my situation I defined an explicit argument matcher, which only triggers the exceptional behavior. This way, I don't need to explicitly specify the "call real method":
`doThrow(new OptimisticLockingFailureException("some concurrency issue")).when(someRepository).save(argThat(shouldTriggerAnException()));`