# How does a Mockito spy know when it is spying?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spy

[This code from the documentation](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) is totally baffling me:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);

when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100); // <--- how does this spy know 
// not to call the real method????

//using the spy calls *real* methods
spy.add("one");
spy.add("two");
```

I get it, Mockito is weird and hardly still in Java. Confusing thing is `spy.*` has to evaluate fully before it knows whether it's wrapped in a `when()` or something. How on earth would the first `spy.*` method not call on the real object but the later ones doe?

Comment: It has been answered before. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method

Comment: @nadirsaghar I don't see how the answer you linked to answers this question.

Comment: Well, it does call the real `size()` method (the method simply doesn't have any side-effects and doesn't alter the state of the instance)

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation the first `when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100)` will actually invoke the real `List.size()` method, see: http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Each subsequent call of course will then return the mocked result.

If you don't want the real method to be called (e.g. `when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn(...)` would probably throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you have to use this pattern: `doReturn(...).when(spy).get(0);`

Comment: This is true.  And I am an advocate of always using `doReturn(...).when(...)` instead of worrying about when you need `doReturn(...).when(...)` and when it's OK to use `when(...).thenReturn(...)`.  In fact, I have posted Mockito answers on this site in which I recommend not using `when(...).thenReturn(...)` at all.

Comment: @DavidWallace do you mean that you recommend to always use doReturn() when using spies, or to always use it, even with mocks? I tend to always use it with spies, but find the classical wen(...).then... more readable and thus use that for mocks.

Comment: My preference is to use it even with mocks.  There is no point learning two syntaxes when just one will cover every case.  And it's difficult to remember all the cases when `when/thenReturn` won't work.  @JBNizet

Comment: @JBNizet - Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/q/11462697/ .  It looks like I incorrectly state that `when` can't be used on spies.  This might have been true at the time that I wrote it; I'm not sure.  So I will go back and correct this answer.  In any case, the basic message of my answer is still true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact implementation, but I can take a guess.

The call to `spy(...)` first proxies the given object and keeps it as a reference to delegate calls.

The call

```
when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100);
```

is practically equivalent to

```
Integer result = spy.size();
OngoingStubbing<Integer> stubbing = when(result); // result is useless
stubbing.thenReturn(100);
```

The first call to `size()` is invoked on the proxy. Internally, it can register the call, pushing it, for example, on a `static` (global) Mockito stack. When you then invoke `when()`, Mockito pops from the stack, recognizes the call to `size()` as needing stubbing and performs whatever logic required to do so.

This can explain why [stubbing in a multithreaded environment](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ) is bad business.

Comment: @DavidWallace You're going to make me look at the source, aren't you?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about going and looking at the source myself, just to remind myself.  But you're actually very close.  There isn't a global stack, and the stubbing call is registered in the spy itself.  But all the other details are right.  I think I downvoted you too hastily, and I'll remove my downvote now.

Comment: Hmm, had to make an insignificant edit to remove my downvote.  I hate this site sometimes.

Comment: ... and the thing created by `spy` doesn't use delegation.  It's in a class that adds logic for stubbing and verification, but for all its methods, it calls the parent method on itself, not on some delegate object.