# Mockito Java doAnswer

Tags: java, mockito

This won't compile. I get an `UnfinishedStubbingException`. I've read the Mockito api and other questions on this site and I think that my syntax shouldn't be wrong, but it fails at `doAnswer(new Answer() {`, so I figure it has to be wrong, but I don't know where. Thanks.

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                ((CrestronNioSocketHandler.NioEventReceiver) args[0]).onDataReceived(new byte[wantedNumber]);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(mockedChannel.read(any(ByteBuffer.class)));
```

Comment: If you get an exception, then you ran it. And if you ran it, then it does compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                ((CrestronNioSocketHandler.NioEventReceiver) args[0]).onDataReceived(new byte[wantedNumber]);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(mockedChannel).read(any(ByteBuffer.class));
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462697/forming-mockito-grammars) about different ways of stubbing with Mockito.